# WPF binding child controls DataContext to HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource item

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext

I have a collection of Barcodes that contains a collection of Positions. How do I set the DataContext of a custom control to a Position item in the collection?

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedPlate.Barcodes}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}"
                                  DataType="{x:Type ControlViewModels:BarcodeViewModel}">

                <TextBox Text="{Binding Code}"/>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <!--The Custom Control that needs to bind to the Position item-->
                        <ControlViews:PositionControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root element in the `ItemTemplate` inherits the `DataContext` so you can remove `DataContext="{Binding}"`.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedPlate.Barcodes}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}"
                                  DataType="{x:Type ControlViewModels:BarcodeViewModel}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Code}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ControlViews:PositionControl />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

In the `PositionControl` you can then bind directly to a public property of a `Position` object assuming you don't explicitly set the `DataContext` of the control somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, I was setting the DataContext in the XAML.